# Is there a .deb version of Howler?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm looking to install [Howler](https://github.com/mricon/howler) on my Ubuntu Server. However, all that page provides is a RPM, not a DEB. Is there a version of Howler available for Debian-based distributions?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/mricon/howler.git && cd howler && python setup.py` doesn't work?

Comment: python setup.py install most likely.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I don't know, I haven't tried it yet. I just like the idea of having a real package that I can manage much better.

Comment: use alien, or build your own package with [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm).

Comment: @Zoredache so no?

Comment: I have no idea.  I was just adding a comment with an alternate path just in case you, or someone else who finds this post in the future needs to know what to do if no package exists.

Comment: @Zoredache okay. after looking at it maybe i'll submit an fpm package to debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a DEB available.

You can [use alien to convert or install an RPM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto):

> Installing an RPM file directly
>
> ```
> sudo alien -i package_file.rpm
> ```
>
> Converting the RPM file to a Debian package
>
> ```
> sudo alien package_file.rpm
> ```

Or use [fpm to build a package from source](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm):

> download the source, unpack, ./configure, make, make install, fpm, deploy.